# Overwrite default list view highlighted color in AppCompat theme

Tags: android, android-listview, android-appcompat, android-theme

My application's main theme inherits from Theme.AppCompat, and I've created a selector that allows for the Ripple effect to take place when you press and focus a button on Lollipop.

However, when I go back to a 4.0 device, it defaults back to an ugly blue color when I focus a list view item. I've looked everywhere for the trait that defines this color hoping to override it without any luck - any idea how I can do this?

Answer (score 5):

Add this to your theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    ...
    <item name="android:listViewStyle">@style/ListViewAppTheme</item>
    <item name="android:listViewWhiteStyle">@style/ListViewAppTheme.White</item>
</style>
 <style name="ListViewAppTheme" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.ListView">
    <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/abc_list_selector_dark</item>
    <item name="android:divider">@drawable/ab_divider_light</item>
    <item name="android:dividerHeight">1px</item>
</style>

<style name="ListViewAppTheme.White" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.ListView.White">
    <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/abc_list_selector_dark</item>
    <item name="android:divider">@drawable/ab_divider_light</item>
    <item name="android:dividerHeight">1px</item>
</style>
```

Change `@drawable/abc_list_selector_dark` to whatever selector you want to use. As an added bonus, I added how to change the listview's divider and its height.

Comment: Can you use a selector of colors for the listSelector, or does it have to be actual drawables?

Comment: You can use a selector of colors. You will still call it `@drawable/my_colors_selector` and instead of using an actual image in your selector, just use @drawable/my_color

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't seem to be working. The list views still seem to be getting that disgusting default blue color from SOMEWHERE, although I can't figure out where.

Answer (score 3):

> Unfortunately doesn't seem to be working. The list views still seem to
>   be getting that disgusting default blue color from SOMEWHERE, although
>   I can't figure out where.

I used to feel like you, both on the *disgusting* and the angry *somewhere* part. However I managed to get rid of it.

If I remember well, the culprit should be `android:listChoiceBackgroundIndicator`. Try this:

```
<style name="MainTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">

    <item name="android:listChoiceBackgroundIndicator">@drawable/my_selector</item>
    <item name="listChoiceBackgroundIndicator">@drawable/my_selector</item>

</style>
```